# scrapy with cssselct

Tags: python, css, regex, css-selectors

I am trying to make an exercise using `cssselect` unfortunately just works when I read the `<h1>` let me show you the example:

the HTML code that I am using for this exercise is the follow:

```
<h1 class="lbl_titulo">3 Bedroom House<span class="subtit"> - Well located house in  the heart of Lapa (Lisbon) </span></h1>

    <div class="bloco-imovel-dados">

                        <div class="bloco-imovel-resumo-dados">
                            <div id="Cpl_modulodadosresumidos_module_holder"     class="modulo-dados-resumidos">

    <h2 class="lbl_descricao_dados">Property Information</h2>

    <ul class="bloco-dados">

        <li>
            <b>Condition:</b> <span>Renewed</span></li>
        <li>
            <b>Living Area:</b><span> 80 m<sup>2</sup></span></li>
        <li>
            <b>Total Area:</b><span> 0 m<sup>2</sup></span></li>
        <li>
            <b>Bathrooms:</b><span> 1 </span></li>
        <li>
            <b>Bedrooms:</b><span> 2 </span></li>
        <li>
            <b>Energy Rating:</b><span> C</span></li>
        <li>
            <b>Construction year:</b><span> 1997</span></li>
        <li>
            <b>ID Property:</b><span> CAS.10.13286</span></li>

    </ul>

</div>

    <div class="row pref-search-results"><script>setTimeout(function(){     $(".pref-search-results").addClass("pref-search-result").removeClass("pref-    search-results") }, 1000)</script>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a class="pref-   property-container" href="http://xxxxxxxxx.com/link-to-image" style="height:    420px;">
            <div class="pref-teaser-shadow"></div>
            <div class="pref-teaser-image">
                <div class="pref-teaser-icons-container bottom">
                    <div class="pref-watchlist-teaser-icon-container">
                        <div class="pref-teaser-icon pref-watchlist-icon active initial-hide"></div>
                        <div class="pref-teaser-icon pref-watchlist-icon inactive "></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pref-teaser-shadow"></div>
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Ranch_style_home_in_Salinas%2C_California.JPG/220px-Ranch_style_home_in_Salinas%2C_California.JPG" title="Link to Image" alt="Link Image">
            </div>
        </a></div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="bloco-imovel-caracteristicas-holder">
                        <div id="Cpl_modulocaracteristicas_module_holder" class="modulo-caracteristicas">
    <a class="pref-property-container" href="http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/link-to-listing" style="height: 420px;">Link 1</a>
    <a class="pref-property-container" href="http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/link-to-listing" style="height: 420px;">Link 2</a>
    <h3 class="lbl_titulo_caracteristicas">Features</h3>
    <div id="Cpl_modulocaracteristicas_div_caracteristicas_gerais" class="modulo-caracteristicas-item  open">
        <ul class="modulo-caracteristicas-conteudo js-caracteristicas-holder">
            <li>
                <span id="features">Garden</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span id="features">Gas Heating</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span id="features">2 garages</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span id="features">Large pool</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="bloco-imovel-texto">
                        <h3 class="lbl_description">
                            Description </h3>
                        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fugaEt harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus.</p>
                    </div>

                     <div class="bloco-imovel-content">
            <!-- Galeria -->
            <div class="bloco-imovel-galeria">
                <div id="Cpl_modulogaleriavertical_module_holder" class="modulo-galeria-vertical">
            <span id="Cpl_modulogaleriavertical_lbl_galeria" class="lbl_galeria"><b>Relevant Information</b></span>

</div>

                    <div id="Cpl_pnl_mapa" class="pnl_mapa">

                        <span id="Cpl_lbl_mapa" class="lbl_mapa"><b>Location:</b></span>
                        <span id="Cpl_lbl_morada" class="lbl_morada">Portugal, Lisboa, Estrela, Lapa</span>
                        <div id="Cpl_modulomapa_module_holder" class="modulo-mapa">

    <div class="bloco-mapa">
        <div id="Cpl_modulomapa_mapa" class="mapa"></div>
        <div id="map-canvas" data-coorgps="36.5194999,-4.7743365"></div> 
    </div>

    </div>


</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bloco-imovel-sidebar">
                <div id="Cpl_moduloinformacaolateral_module_holder" class="modulo-informacao-lateral">

    <div class="informacao">
        <div class="info1">
            <div class="lbl_titulo">Agent John Doe</div>
            <div class="lbl_subtitulo">
            Contact Information
            </div>
            <div class="lbl_resumo">
            Phone Number: 0800-1111<br><b><a href="mailto:casa@casa.pt">casa@casa.pt</a></b><br><b></b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<a class="pref-property-container" href="http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/link-to-listing" style="height: 420px;">Link 3</a>

</div></div></div>
```

So of course I do the installations:

```
!pip install lxml
!pip install cssselect
from lxml import html,etree
```

I open and read the file

```
with open(r'listing.html', "r") as f:
    page = f.read()
tree = html.fromstring(page)
```

And then I would like to scrapy the follow information:

```
Name of the property
Number of bathrooms
Number of bedrooms
Living Area
Energy Rating
Description
Agent Name
Extract the location of the property
```

so what I try to do is:

```
Selector_Example = "h1.lbl_titulo"
print('Example -> Property type: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_Example)[0].text))
```

and I got the answer:

`Example -> Property type: 3 Bedroom House`

and when I try with the other examples I always get an error:

```
#Number of bathrooms
Selector_1 = "li:nth-child(1)"
print('Bathrooms: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_1)[0].text))
print('')
# this returns just the word Bathrooms: but I tried to use `li.b` and does not work as well.

#Number of bedrooms
Selector_2 = "li:nth-child(2)"
print('Bedrooms: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_2)[0].text))
print('')
# this returns just the word Bedrooms: but I tried to use `li.b` and does not work as well.

#Living Area
Selector_3 = "li:nth-child(3)"
print('Total area: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_3)[0].text))
print('')
this returns just the words Living Area: but I tried to use `li.b` and does not work as well.

#Energy Rating
Selector_4 = "li:nth-child(4)"

#Description
Selector_5 = "h3.lbl_description"
print('Description: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_5)[0].text))
print('')
# This returns the word Description: Description but not the description.



#Agent Name
Selector_6 = "div.lbl_titulo"
print('Agent name: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_6)[0].text))
print('')
# This gives my in fact the agent name: Agent John Doe

#Extract the location of the property
Selector_7 = "div.Cpl_lbl_morada.lbl_morada"
print('Location: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_7)[0].text))
# I got direct : IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anybody knows what I am doing wrong and how actually amend this code? Thanks in advance for the advises!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example:

```
#Number of bedrooms
Selector_2 = "li:nth-child(2)"
print('Bedrooms: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_2)[0].text))
```

as far as I know in this case `"li:nth-child(2)"` return `'\n       '` what is the 2nd `li` element, `"li:nth-child(3)"` returns 3rd `li`.
If you want to get `Bedrooms` you need to use

```
#Number of bedrooms
Selector_2 = "li:nth-child(5) span"
print('Bedrooms: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_2)[0].text))
```

`li:nth-child(5)` because `Bedrooms` is 5th `li` element and `span` because you want information from the span element which is in the `li`

EDIT.
The strings you assign to `Selector_` variables are `CSS` so you can use the same notation like in CSS file. So `li.b` means `<li class='b'>`

Comment: thank you very much, it works for all but `description` ... if I do

    #Description
    Selector_5 = "h3.lbl_description"
    print('Description: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_5)[0].text))
    print('')
    # This returns the word Description: Description but not the description.

and when I try to put `scan` or `<p>` I always got an Error... any Idea why?

Comment: @fachc And why you cannot do `Selector_5 = "div.bloco-imovel-texto p"`

Comment: thank you very much, I was trying all the possible ways but with the `h3`, it worked perfectly your way cheers!

Comment: sorry to bother you again but I am stuck again with the css selector project ... I am trying to scrapy on link (http://xxxxxxxxx.com/link-to-image) and I have trying all the possible ways and I got error or just a empty string:

`Selector_8 = "a.pref-property-container "`
`print('Link: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_8)[0].text)) `

This one gives me just the word [link:]  and nothing else..

I tried as well :

`'span[class=pref-property-container] a::attr(href)').extract()[0]`

but the result is as well an error, do you have any idea what is wrong there?

Comment: And the last question I need to scrapy all the _features_ so I do:

`Selector_9 = "div.bloco-imovel-caracteristicas-holder span"`
`print('features: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_9)[0].text))`

But I got just the first one and not all of them? is there a way to grab all the 4 features?

Comment: @fachc 
about link you need to use:
`Selector_8 = "a.pref-property-container"`
`print('Link: {}'.format(tree.cssselect(Selector_8)[0].get('href')))`
about last question you can do `print('features: {}'.format(', '.join([x.text for x in tree.cssselect(Selector_9)])))`, `tree.cssselect(Selector_9)` return list so you can iterate through it.